# mongodb aggregate get current date

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm using [metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) and I have native mongodb query. I want to filter documents created yesterday. The problem is that I only have json. Is there any way to compute yesterday?

my json is:

```
[...
{
    "$match": {
      "createdAt": { "$ne": "$yesterday" },
    }
},
...]
```

Comment: can you please share the sample document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Metabase does not allow to use Date() to get now Date. also you should notice that dateFromString is available in version 3.6 of mongoDB and newer but another problem here is i think dateFromString does not work well with now Date in aggregate and mongoDB return an error that you should pass a string to convert to Date in dateFromString! 
so i suggest to you to get yesterday Date in metabase write code something like this :

```
[{
  "$project": {
      "user": 1,
      "createdAt": 1,
      "yesterday": {
          "$subtract": [ISODate(), 86400000]
      }
  }
},
{
 "$project": {
     "user": 1,
     "yesterday": 1,
     "createdAt": 1,
     "dateComp": { "$cmp": ["$yesterday", "$createdAt"] }
 }
},
{
"$match": { 
     "dateComp": -1 
}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Metabase, you can actually use dates relative to today, such as yesterday, by using `Date()`. This is a workaround [currently implemented in the mongo driver for metabase](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/eac6adc13207b307d4f2f84bfcdf289270b33c48/modules/drivers/mongo/src/metabase/driver/mongo/query_processor.clj#L545). This workaround internally handles the date as a String, so we have to parse it before trying to use *yesterday* as a Date.

```
[
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "todayHandledAsString": Date(),
        "todayHandledAsDate": {"$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": Date()
        }}
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 1,
        "todayHandledAsString": 1,
        "todayHandledAsDate": 1,
        "yesterday": {
            "$subtract": ["$todayHandledAsDate", 86400000]
        }
    }
}
]
```

Unfortunately, Metabase also disallows operations or comments, so we have to use a hardcoded value of `86400000` instead of `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`, which is a single day in millis.

Answer (score 0):

pay_status is a field of current table. After map them,then you can choose.

```
[       
{$match:{{pay_status}}},
{$match:{{pay_time}}},
{$project:{...}}
]
```